# List of the most common causes and solutions to bugs compiling bibliographies in TeX

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors, compiling, biber

I start using the `Texmaker` on my home PC, when I try to run my files I get an error message from this type:

```
INFO - This is biber 0.9.2

INFO - Logfile is 'bibertest.blg'

FATAL - Cannot find control file 'bibertest.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?

Process exited with error(s)
```

I used this MWE (from a previous post)

```
%%% Tex File
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{NumFactorsTest.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text is here.
\textcite{Akaike1973}
\textcite{Akaike1987}


\printbibliography

\end{document}


%%% BIB file
@InProceedings{Akaike1973,
   author = {H. Akaike},
   title = {Information theory and an extension of the maximum likelihood principle},
   editor = {B. N. Petrov and F. Csaki},
   booktitle = {2nd International Symposium on Information Theory},
   pages = {267-281},
   year = {1973},
   location = {Budapest: Akademiai Kiado} 
}

@article{Akaike1987,
   author = {Akaike},
   title = {Factor analysis and AIC},
   journal = {Psychometrika},
   volume = {52},
   number = {3},
   pages = {317-332},
   year = {1987}
}
```

`.blg` file:

```
[2] Config.pm:324> INFO - This is Biber 2.1
[2] Config.pm:327> INFO - Logfile is 'bibertest.blg'
[232] biber-MSWIN:273> INFO - === %a %b %e, %Y, %H:%M:%S
[597] Utils.pm:162> ERROR - Cannot find control file 'bibertest.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?
[598] Biber.pm:110> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

`.log` file (relevant parts):

```
("C:\Program Files\Miktex 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.sty"
Package: biblatex 2015/04/19 v3.0 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
("C:\Program Files\Miktex 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex2.sty"
Package: biblatex2 2015/04/19 v3.0 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/A
B)


Package biblatex Info: No input encoding detected.
(biblatex) Assuming 'ascii'.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex) Assuming data encoding 'ascii'.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'bibertest.bbl' not found.
No file bibertest.bbl.
```

I check into some potential solutions:

---

1. Update `MikTeX` and configured `Texmaker` - [Biblatex + Biber + Texmaker + MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/biblatex-biber-texmaker-miktex)

I updated `MikTeX` and configured `Texmaker` to use biber as follow

[image]

---

2. [Cache folders](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140814/biblatex-biber-fails-with-a-strange-error-about-missing-recode-data-xml-file)

I check for cache folders in temporary files

```
  C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp (Windows 7)
```

but I did not found any cache folder of the type `par-<hex_encoded_username>\cache-*`.

---

3. Mismatch in files - ([Bibliography aux file mismatch (.aux.bcf versus .bcf)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163967/bibliography-aux-file-mismatch-aux-bcf-versus-bcf))

I checked for mismatch between files.

---

4. Control file (.bcf) - 
   [Error message when using biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21486/error-message-when-using-biber)

I also checked other solution to address the issue of not finding the control file, but was not useful.

---

Are there any additional causes to this bug and which are the alternative solutions I can try? List of most common causes of bugs and solutions could be also a good way to systematize this issue, if this is considered relevant (but I don't know how many more posts I should look to get a solution). Some state-of-art about `biber` updates and efforts to correct these bugs, if found relevant.

The way I see it there is lot of really good information on `tex.stackexchange`, but is not gathered, which difficult the task to solve issues with `biber` and bibliographies in general, which is a important topic for all kind of research.

Note: When I first run the `PdfLaTeX` before running `biber` I get a warning message  of a busy `synctex` file. I solve this issue using this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168324/how-do-i-close-a-busy-synctex-gz-file), but the initial bug remains.

Comment: I trust the message at the top of your post is from back when you hadn't done the update yet, right? Biber 0.9.2 is hopelessly outdated. You should have Biber 2.1 and `biblatex` 3.0 now. Other than that it is quite impossible to say what problem you are facing right now: We would need to know relevant parts of the `.log` (but please not all of it) and the `.blg` files.

Comment: Your question, I'm afraid might not really fit into the Q&A style of this site. We do have some "list of" questions, but yours carries a potential of subjectiveness. Other than that I would say the most common causes for troubles with the bibliography are: 1) [Failure to run Biber/BibTeX and LaTeX the appropriate number of times](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/) (often caused by [editors not being incorrectly set up](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/)) 2) Version mismatches between Biber and `biblatex`. 3) [Biber's infamous cache bug](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/)

Comment: But to be honest if you have this `synctex` issue, your editor/installation might not be correctly set up in the first place.

Comment: From what I see in your screenshot you might have fallen into the "Use a build subdirectory" trap. See https://smidgeonpigeon.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/texmaker-subfolder-build-biber/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184204/texstudio-biber-build-folder, and http://sourceforge.net/p/biblatex-biber/feature-requests/3/. The solution is the `--output-directory` option to Biber as described in §3.3.1. *Control file*, p. 30, of [the Biber docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf): `biber --output-directory=build %` should do it.

Comment: @moewe The infamous cache bug should be resolved with the dev-version and some time in the future with TL. :-) That is good news i think.

Comment: @moewe Yes, I updated the version on my home PC, the current version is biber 2.1.  `synctex` problem was related to spaces between words in the File name directory, so don't seem to be the problem I think. I will check your last comment.

Comment: @moewe I updated the question with `.log` (the parts I considered relevants, but if is needed additional information let me know) and `.blg` files.

Comment: Well, the `.log` file does not really help, the problem lies with Biber not finding the `.bcf. With your set up, my best guess is [Finding LaTex output file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152843/35864), here and the duplicate etc., etc.

Comment: I finally made it, but is was non-trivial. I reinstall `biblatex` packages (because I already tried reinstall Biber). Afterwards the cache folder `par-<hex_encoded_username>\cache-*` was finally created at temporary files (I didn't have it at the beginning) and deleted it. I found that was also using [Intermediate Files in Another Folder](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35052/placing-intermediate-and-output-files-in-another-folder), so I recommend that at beginning  probably is better to use the original output files. It worked in my particular case. Thank you for you help @moewe.

Comment: @moewe a answer that list your recommendations could be helpful, in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case the problem was using the 'Use a "build" subdirectory for output files option' of your editor. When Biber is invoked it looks for the `.bcf` file (in fact, Biber "compiles" the `.bcf`). But if the `.bcf` file has been moved to another subdirectory Biber is unaware of, Biber cannot find the file.
For exactly this reason Biber has the `--output-directory` and `--input-directory` options, as explained in [Finding LaTex output files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152843/35864). Most editors are, however, unaware of this nice feature and do not incorporate this into their 'Use a "build" subdirectory for output files option' feature, so you will have to do that yourself.

The consensus on this site seems to be: Only use such 'Use a "build" subdirectory for output files option' option if you know what you are (and what it is !) doing. If you have a nice folder structure set up for your document, you will be able to cope with the temporary files produced by LaTeX and friends just fine.

---

In my experience the most frequent issued faced when trying to get `biblatex` and Biber running are the following. You will note that only one of them can really be considered a bug, albeit one that was introduced by an upstream package.

1. **Failure to run Biber.** Especially beginners using editor/IDE environments often don't realise that one has to run an external programme on the files. One does not only need LaTeX to compile the file, but Biber as well. See the often viewed [Question mark instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). For those wishing to have their editor support Biber there is then also [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).
2. **Mismatching `biblatex` and Biber versions.** Of course it is always recommended to keep all components of the system up to date with regular updates. This is even more crucial for `biblatex` and Biber, since a particular version of `biblatex` only works together with a specific version of Biber. Refer to the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for the *Biber/Biblatex compatibility matrix* (table 1 on page 6 in version 3.0 of the doc).
   The warning one gets when this problem occurs is along the lines of

   > `Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.5, expected version 2.4`

   Indeed this is only a warning and in some cases the compilation still goes through if you press on, but more often than not this causes trouble and grief further down the road.
   One has to keep in mind here that the `biblatex` control file (bcf) version does not necessarily agree with either `biblatex`'s or Biber's version. Currently, `biblatex` is at version 3.0, Biber at 2.1 and the corresponding bcf version is 2.5.
3. **Biber's infamous cache bug.** Sometimes Biber chokes on its cache folder - is has not been properly unpacked or otherwise been corrupted.
   This is a known problem and makes itself known with strange Biber errors and warnings along the lines of

   > `Use of uninitialized value $llabel in concatenation (.) or string at Biber.pm line 1741`

   and

   > `data source C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\par-416e6a61\cache-46f2da95c5284272f49f4e60b997c7e3f24afb19\recode_data.xml not found in .`

   As explained in [Biblatex/biber fails with a strange error about missing recode_data.xml file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/) this can be remedied by deleting Biber's cache folder. In the linked question, one of Biber's developers announced that the relevant Perl package has been updated and so the bug should be removed in future versions of Biber.
4. **Non-standard, non-uniform or malformed `.bib` file.** Often, this does not lead to errors or warnings, but to awkward output. Sometimes people just download reference information off the internet or let their reference manager export a `.bib` file without reviewing the resulting `.bib` file. These files can contain awkward constructs such as `note = {\url{www.example.com} accessed 1. September 2014}`, when the `biblatex` way would be `url = {www.example.com}, urldate = {2014-09-01}`. People sometimes use `@misc` for works where the `@online` entry type would be more appropriate. For a list of supported types, their fields and the meaning of those refer to §2 *Database Guide* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). A good example for a clean `.bib` file for `biblatex` is [`biblatex-examples.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/biblatex-examples.bib).

It might go without saying, but if you have identified a problem and have fixed it it is always a good idea to delete temporary files (`.aux`, `.bcf`, ...) to make sure the compilation can got through without any legacy problems in the temporary files.